# nginx passenger recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while sending to client

Tags: json, nginx, http-post, sinatra, passenger

I'm posting some `json` to a `Sinatra` `post` `route` on `nginx`.  I'm getting a `500 ISE` error.  I don't know why this is happening.

The `JSON` is good, the url is valid (showing `404` when pulled up in a browser, as expected (it's set to throw `404` with no `JSON`).

```
url = URI.parse('https://example.com/t_test')
# http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, 443)
http.use_ssl = true if url.scheme == 'https'
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path, {
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
})
request.body = json_data
response = http.request(request)

puts "Response Code: #{response.code}", ''
puts "Response Body: #{response.body}"
```

```
recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while sending to client
```

What is happening, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

That `request` `route` had instructions to write to a file.  That was creating the `ISE`.  I wrote a method inside the `helper` block that cleared it up.